# virt-install with kickstart file using LVM fails

Tags: kickstart, rhel7, virt-install

I'm trying to install a VM using `virt-install` using a kickstart file. I've tried both RHEL 7.0 and RHEL 7.1. In both cases using LVM seems to make the installation fail. After a timeout it drops me to the `dracut:/#` prompt and informs me that I can find information about the failure using `journalctl`. I've done this and have found nothing.

Looking at the `/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt` file, though, shows errors related to `multipathd`:

```
...
mulitpathd[116]: vda: failed to get path uid
...
multipathd[116]: uevent trigger error
...
multipathd[116]: vda: spurious uevent, path already in pathvec
multipathd[116]: vda: failed to get path uid
multipathd[116]: uevent trigger error
...
```

There are not other obvious errors.

When using simpler partitions the installation goes through cleanly.

The lvm partitioning scheme in the kickstart file that fails:

```
ignoredisk --only-use=vda
bootloader --location=mbr --boot-drive=vda
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=vda
part /boot --fstype=xfs --size=500 --ondisk=vda
part pv.16 --size=1 --grow --ondisk=vda
volgroup vg00 pv.16
logvol swap --fstype=swap --size=500 --name=swap --vgname=vg00
logvol /home --fstype=xfs --size=300 --name=home --vgname=vg00
logvol / --fstype=xfs --size=1 --grow --name=root --vgname=vg00
```

This is the simple partitioning scheme in the kickstart file that works:

```
ignoredisk --only-use=vda
bootloader --location=mbr --boot-drive=vda
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=vda
part /boot --fstype=xfs --size=500
part swap --fstype=swap --size=500
part / --fstype=xfs --grow --size=1
```

All other inputs are identical so I'm quite certain that the LVM portion is the culprit. `ksvalidator` doesn't tell me anything either.

Has anyone else experienced this?

**EDIT:**  In previous attempts I was running the `virt-install` command as a regular user with sudo. I logged in as root and ran the same command which seemed to work. To a point, anyway. I am now able to get RHEL 7.0 to kickstart with an LVM configuration, but RHEL 7.1 now simply throws `An unknown error occured`. When I submitted the bug report it merely said `SettingsNotFoundError` with little indication as to which settings it could not find. There are a few existing bug reports with this error but none seem to follow the same path that led up to it.

As an aside, I'm baffled that Red Hat still has problems with both `virt-manager` and `virt-install`. Additionally, it took two attempts to get RHEL 7.0 to actually start the installation. The first attempt left me at the `Installation Summary` screen with the installation media section stating `Error setting up base repository`. I re-ran the same command with the same installation media and kickstart file. This attempt went through cleanly.

Comment: 300 MB seems _much too small_ for `/home`.

Comment: The size of `/home` is moot. The issue arises even when a separate `/home` partition is _not_ created.